# Custom WP Meta Box - Use data from within the post screen inside meta box

Tags: metabox

I have created a custom Meta Box that appears on my WP post edit screen. I would like this box to be an image preview of sorts, the URL for the image should be controlled by another field on the post edit screen.

For example:

- I have a select field with a range of values from 5 - 10.
- I have a number of images with following urls: 'example-5.jpg' to 'example-10.jpg'
- In my custom meta box I have an image with src of '/img/example-'$val'.jpg'

So, as a user selects the value from custom field the image within custom meta box will appear.

Can anyone provide some guidance on creating something like this? Im guess I will need to use JS for the realtime rendering of the image but not sure how to actually get the value from the custom field..

Comment: what control the selected field ? the name of a file ? the number of images ?

Comment: Use `wp_locallize_script' to pass the post ID, or attachment info to your JS.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script